# Same Options For Different Django Admin Class

Tags: python, django, django-admin

This should evident but I dont know how to do it.
How do I Apply the same options for instance a exclude for different model and different admin class

-- admin.py

```
class Tabla1(admin.ModelAdmin):
   exclude('tenant')
   ...

class Tabla2(admin.ModelAdmin):
   exclude('tenant')
   ...

class Tabla3(admin.ModelAdmin):
   exclude('tenant')
   ...
```

That I want is exclude the same tenant field in the tables. I have the same field in several tables. In fact I have several actions(same actions) to do for the different admin models.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make a base admin class that you can inherit from:

```
class TablaBaseAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    class Meta:
        exclude = ('tenant',)

class Tabla1Admin(TablaBaseAdmin):
    pass

class Tabla2Admin(TablaBaseAdmin):
    pass

class Tabla3Admin(TablaBaseAdmin):
    pass
```